# Exclude certain accounts in SharePoint Profile Import

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, user-profile-service

We are trying to exclude certain account from SharePoint Imports. Basically we have service accounts that we need to exclude from the import and was wondering if this can be done via editing connection filters. 
For example we want to create a rule to exclude AD accounts that starts with: **svc**

Comment: What version of SharePoint ?are you using the User Profile Sync or ADI? DO you have account type field set in AD?

Comment: SharePoint 2010 so we are using profile sync. I am not sure about account type field part.